# How to find the leaf nodes with recursion in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to wrap my head around recursion and like to solve a similar problem like this one: [Recursively find all children from parent menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038918/recursively-find-all-children-from-parent-menu).

The difference between my problem and the one from the example above is that I need the result of the function to be a list of leaf nodes. So if you take the JSON data below and I wanted to know what the leaf nodes of menuId 1001 are, I expect the result to be `["1005", "1007", "1009"]`. If I wanted to know what the leaf nodes starting from 1004 are, I expect the result to be `["1007", "1009"]`

```
[
    {"menuId":"1001","depth":"1","parentId":"0"},
    {"menuId":"1002","depth":"1","parentId":"0"},
    {"menuId":"1003","depth":"2","parentId":"1001"},
    {"menuId":"1004","depth":"2","parentId":"1001"},
    {"menuId":"1005","depth":"3","parentId":"1003"}, 
    {"menuId":"1006","depth":"3","parentId":"1004"}, 
    {"menuId":"1007","depth":"4","parentId":"1006"}, 
    {"menuId":"1008","depth":"4","parentId":"1006"}, 
    {"menuId":"1009","depth":"5","parentId":"1008"},
]
```

I've tried altering the code from the link to solve my problem, but I can't seem to figure it out:

```
    function getChildren(array, id) {
    return array.reduce((r, { menuId }) => {
        if (array.filter(x => x.parentId === id).length === 0) {
            r.push(menuId);
        } else {
            getChildren(array, menuId)
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
```

Any advice or help will be appreciated.

Comment: "list of children which aren't parent of any other children"... do you mean ["leaf nodes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#:~:text=an%20external%20node%20(also%20known%20as%20an%20outer%20node%2C%20leaf%20node%2C%20or%20terminal%20node)%20is%20any%20node%20that%20does%20not%20have%20child%20nodes.)? "most deeply nested child" would be child with most ancestors, i.e. `1009` only, in your example.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll edit my question accordingly

Comment: Also, why is `1002` not in your expected result?

Comment: Because I want to know what the leaf nodes are starting from menuId 1001.

Comment: Ah, I see. I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Reworked because I can't read.

Recursion is not a very efficient approach, given that the data structure you have is linearised. Thus, I first convert the data into an actual tree structure, where recursion can shine.

A wrinkle is that you don't have a proper tree, since the root node is missing. I also assumed you don't want your input data changed, so I cloned your data for a non-destructive approach. Allowing the `items` data to be changed (adding the `children` property) instead of copying, and inserting a dummy root node would have considerably simplified the code.

```js
const items = [
    {"menuId":"1001","depth":"1","parentId":"0"},
    {"menuId":"1002","depth":"1","parentId":"0"},
    {"menuId":"1003","depth":"2","parentId":"1001"},
    {"menuId":"1004","depth":"2","parentId":"1001"},
    {"menuId":"1005","depth":"3","parentId":"1003"}, 
    {"menuId":"1006","depth":"3","parentId":"1004"}, 
    {"menuId":"1007","depth":"4","parentId":"1006"}, 
    {"menuId":"1008","depth":"4","parentId":"1006"}, 
    {"menuId":"1009","depth":"5","parentId":"1008"},
];

const tree = {};
function treeify(items) {
  const roots = [];
  const lookup = {};
  for (const item of items) {
    lookup[item.menuId] = { ...item, children: [] };
  }
  for (const item of Object.values(lookup)) {
    if (item.parentId in lookup) {
      lookup[item.parentId].children.push(item);
    } else {
      roots.push(item);
    }
  }
  return roots;
}

function leafNodes(root) {
  if (root.children.length) {
    return root.children.flatMap(leafNodes);
  } else {
    return [root];
  }
}

const roots = treeify(items);
const node1001 = roots.find(item => item.menuId == "1001");
const leafNodesOf1001 = leafNodes(node1001);
console.log(leafNodesOf1001);
console.log(leafNodesOf1001.map(item => item.menuId));
// ["1005", "1007", "1009"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This works as long as you know that the input is going to be at the top level (1001 or 1002 in this case). Starting from a nested level this will not work (i.e. 1004) as roots.find will result in undefined. I should've specified in my question, which I will edit now.

Comment: It will still work, it's just the matter of finding the node. You could let `treeify` also return the `lookup`, in which case looking up the node is trivial.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks I finally figured it out :). Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

One approach which is not particularly efficient, but is very simple, is to recursively scan the data for the children of a given `id`.  If there are none, we're at a leaf (assuming the id actually is in the input).  If there are children, we just `flatMap` our function over their `id`s.  It looks like this:

```js
const leafDescendents = (items) => (id) => {
  const children = items .filter (({parentId}) => id == parentId) 
  return children .length == 0 
    ? items .find (({menuId}) => menuId == id) ? [id] : [] 
    : children .map (child => child.menuId) .flatMap (leafDescendents (items))
}

const items = [{menuId: "1001", depth: "1", parentId: "0"}, {menuId: "1002", depth: "1", parentId: "0"}, {menuId: "1003", depth: "2", parentId: "1001"}, {menuId: "1004", depth: "2", parentId: "1001"}, {menuId: "1005", depth: "3", parentId: "1003"}, {menuId: "1006", depth: "3", parentId: "1004"}, {menuId: "1007", depth: "4", parentId: "1006"}, {menuId: "1008", depth: "4", parentId: "1006"}, {menuId: "1009", depth: "5", parentId: "1008"}];


['1001', '1008', '1009', '0', '999'] .forEach (
  (id) => console .log (`"${id}":\t${JSON .stringify (leafDescendents (items) (id))}`)
)
```

The only slightly odd bit is that this:

```js
    ? items .find (({menuId}) => menuId == id) ? [id] : []
```

looks like it should just be this:

```js
    ? [id]
```

And it could be, if either

- (a) you know that the inputs will always be the `menuId` of one of your items
- (b) you don't mind that unknown inputs will return their own value, for instance

  ```js
  leafDescendents (items) ("999") //=> ["999"]
  ```

If you don't like that oddity, and you suspect that you might be feeding it missing `id`s, then keep the line intact.  Otherwise, you can use the simpler line.

Comment: Thank you! I already accepted an answer, but this is more what I initially was aiming for. I'm going to play around with your code and see if I can wrap my head around it. FYI I did already notice that changing the code to the 'simpler line' doesn't work and will always return an empty array.

Comment: Right.  That's because I made a mistake in "simpler line."  I'll fix it right now.... done.